# How to capture specific string inside a double quotes

Tags: regex

I have a set of strings in the below format, i want to capture the value inside the double quotes.
**Input:**

```
"icici","1001","50.0"
"hdfc","2001","10.0","20.0"
```

**Expected output from substitution parameter:**

```
\0 match icici and hdfc
\1 match 1001  and 2001
\2 match 50.0 and 10.0
\3 match 20.0
```

I tried the below regex but its not working properly, could you please help?

```
((?:")([0-9A-Za-z.]+)(?:",?))+
```

Comment: What is the output that you are getting? Also it would be great if  yo u specify which language you are using it in

Comment: @nu11p01n73R, language is java. I am fine, if you show the output in http://regex101.com/ simulator also.

Comment: Do you know how many values could contain a line? (min and max)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, the values are not in fixed length, sometimes it will be 5 or 10 or 20 values per line. Is it possible to solve this problem using regex? I am fine you can consider min=1 and max=20 values per line.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but probably not the best way. Note that your datas look like a csv structure. Use a csv tool for that.

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

`/\"([a-z0-9.]+)\"/mi`     allow character puts in [allow char]

[live demo](http://regex101.com/r/fD6zV2/1)

**php**

```
$re = "/\"([a-z0-9.]+)\"/mi";
$str = "\"icici\",\"1001\",\"50.0\"\n\"hdfc\",\"2001\",\"10.0\",\"20.0\"";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
    var_dump( $matches[1]);
```

or

```
 $str="";
    if(count($matches[1])>0) foreach($matches[1] as $k=>$v){
        $str .="\\$k"."->".$v."&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    }
    echo $str ;
```

**output:**

```
array (size=7)
  0 => string 'icici' (length=5)
  1 => string '1001' (length=4)
  2 => string '50.0' (length=4)
  3 => string 'hdfc' (length=4)
  4 => string '2001' (length=4)
  5 => string '10.0' (length=4)
  6 => string '20.0' (length=4)
```

or

`\0->icici  \1->1001  \2->50.0  \3->hdfc  \4->2001  \5->10.0  \6->20.0`

Comment: In the above demo link, if i give \0 in the substitution, its matching the entire string but i want to store \0 ->icici  \1 -> 1001  \2->50.0

Comment: please give me your input and output after replacing

Comment: i think this may not possible use only regex. this is solved by using regex and others